# Prove summation formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to show the following? $$\sum_{s \geq 0} \binom{n+s-1}{s} t^{s} = \frac{1}{(1-t)^{n}}$$ For the case of $n=1$ it follows from a geometric series argument, I suppose.

Comment: Differentiate ... this will give you the inductive step.

Comment: Taylor series for $(1-t)^{-n}$ a/k/a binomial formula.

Comment: Stars and bars is helpful. Perhaps by multiplying a lot of geometrics.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any real $ x $ such that $ \left|x\right|<1 $, we have : $$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x^{n}}=\frac{1}{1-x} $$

Differentiating the first side $ p $ times $ \left(p\in\mathbb{N}\right) $, gives : $ \sum\limits_{n=p}^{+\infty}{\frac{n!}{\left(n-p\right)!}x^{n-p}} \cdot $

Then differentiating the second side $ p $ times gives : $ \frac{p!}{\left(1-x\right)^{p+1}} \cdot$

We get a new equation that becomes after dividing both sides by $ p! $ : $$ \sum_{n=p}^{+\infty}{\binom{n}{p}x^{n-p}}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{p+1}} $$

Thus, for any natural number $ n $ and real $ t,\ \left|t\right|<1 $, we have : $$ \frac{1}{\left(1-t\right)^{n}}=\sum_{s=n-1}^{+\infty}{\binom{s}{n-1}t^{s+1-n}}=\sum_{s=0}^{+\infty}{\binom{n+s-1}{n-1}t^{s}}=\sum_{s=0}^{+\infty}{\binom{n+s-1}{s}t^{s}} $$

Because $ \left(\forall \left(n,k\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}\mid k\leq n\right),\ \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k} \cdot $